# How to modify the multiple target profit by excluding the last order?

Tags: algorithmic-trading, trading, mql4, metatrader4, forex

I created this Modify Take Profit function but this will calculate all the total orders.
How to remove the last order? want it to calculate the average price without the last order

```
void ModifyTakeProfit()
{
   double point=MarketInfo(OrderSymbol(),MODE_POINT);
   double tp1,tp2,bbep,bsize; tp1=0;tp2=0;bbep=0;bsize=0;
   for (int i=OrdersTotal()-1; i>=0; i--) 
   { 
      if(OrderSelect(i,SELECT_BY_POS,MODE_TRADES)==false) break;
      if(OrderSymbol()==Symbol() && OrderMagicNumber()==OrderMagicNumber())
      {
         if(OrderType()==OP_BUY)
         {
            tp1=OrderTakeProfit();
            bbep += OrderOpenPrice()*OrderLots(); 
            bsize+= OrderLots();
         }
      }      
   }
   if (bbep>0) 
   { 
      bbep/=bsize; 
      tp1=bbep + TakeProfit*point;
      if(TakeProfit!=0)
         tp1=NormalizeDouble(tp1,(int)MarketInfo(OrderSymbol(),MODE_DIGITS));
      else 
         tp1=0;
   }
   for (int i=OrdersTotal()-1; i>=0; i--)
   { 
      if(OrderSelect(i,SELECT_BY_POS,MODE_TRADES)==false) break;
      if(OrderSymbol()==Symbol() && OrderMagicNumber()==OrderMagicNumber())
      {
         if(OrderType()==OP_BUY)
         {
            tp2=OrderTakeProfit();
            if(tp1!=tp2)
            {   
               if(!OrderModify(OrderTicket(),OrderOpenPrice(),OrderStopLoss(),tp1,0,Blue))
                  Print ("Error: ", GetLastError());
            }
         }
      }      
   }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Your last order will be in the first position (FIFO) - so just adjust your for loops to loop to lower bound of 1 instead of 0.

```cpp
void ModifyTakeProfit()
{
   double point=MarketInfo(OrderSymbol(),MODE_POINT);
   double tp1,tp2,bbep,bsize; tp1=0;tp2=0;bbep=0;bsize=0;
   for (int i=OrdersTotal()-1; i>=1; i--) 
   { 
      if(OrderSelect(i,SELECT_BY_POS,MODE_TRADES)==false) break;
      if(OrderSymbol()==Symbol() && OrderMagicNumber()==OrderMagicNumber())
      {
         if(OrderType()==OP_BUY)
         {
            tp1=OrderTakeProfit();
            bbep += OrderOpenPrice()*OrderLots(); 
            bsize+= OrderLots();
         }
      }      
   }
   if (bbep>0) 
   { 
      bbep/=bsize; 
      tp1=bbep + TakeProfit*point;
      if(TakeProfit!=0)
         tp1=NormalizeDouble(tp1,(int)MarketInfo(OrderSymbol(),MODE_DIGITS));
      else 
         tp1=0;
   }
   for (int i=OrdersTotal()-1; i>=1; i--)
   { 
      if(OrderSelect(i,SELECT_BY_POS,MODE_TRADES)==false) break;
      if(OrderSymbol()==Symbol() && OrderMagicNumber()==OrderMagicNumber())
      {
         if(OrderType()==OP_BUY)
         {
            tp2=OrderTakeProfit();
            if(tp1!=tp2)
            {   
               if(!OrderModify(OrderTicket(),OrderOpenPrice(),OrderStopLoss(),tp1,0,Blue))
                  Print ("Error: ", GetLastError());
            }
         }
      }      
   }
}
```

Comment: Not a very robust solution. If there are any other orders being placed on the account (either manually or by another EA) then this method will fail. Much better to use a sequence of magic numbers from a set base for each order, you could then use this to work out the last placed order.

Comment: as per my comment, your solution would lead to problems should (which can be quite likely) there be any other orders placed on the account. You should never rely on the position from `OrdersTotal()` to determine the sequence in which orders were placed. The function is not meant for that. In fact, the documentation for `OrderSelect()` specifically states: _Consecutive selection of orders using the SELECT_BY_POS parameter returns information in the sequence in which it was received from the trading server. Sorting of the resulting list of orders cannot be guaranteed._

Comment: this method wont work..it still close all the position when the take profit is modified